# Does botbuilder-storage-postgres require a middleware?

Tags: node.js, botframework

User arulvelug-hexaware (https://github.com/arulvelug-hexaware) asked the question in issues on the package:

> No I am not getting any errors. I dont see the data in table.

AND

> Should we need to write a middle ware ? Or how do we write this to storage.
>   Could please provide me an example

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating the storage adapter is demonstrated in the README (see [Sample Usage](https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/botbuilder-storage-postgres#sample-usage)). Writing data is as easy as calling `<whateverYouCalledYourStorageObject>.write(<whateverObjectYouWantToStore>)`. Whether you do that as part of a middleware or not is up to you.

For more detailed information, check out [the Microsoft botbuilder-core storage interface documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/storage?view=botbuilder-ts-latest).